# Annotation to add the latest field value into HashMap

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to write Annotation in Java, to keep the value of given field in HashMap. 


For example, using @Keepdata (Keepdata is an annotation) on specified field will store the latest value of the field value in the HashMap.

> @Keepdata double myDouble;
>   double mySecondDouble;

Creating instance of Keepdata and using method, for example bind(); should add the value of myDouble, but not mySecondDouble to the hashmap in the Keepdata annotation.

> Keepdata kd = new Keepdata(...) 
>   kd.bind(); // adding the actual values of fields to hashmap

How to store this informations in the Keepdata instance of annotation? Could you suggest me the proper way of solving this problem?

Comment: that's a bit unclear. What is your hashmap? What you want to do is refresh your hashmap each time your double value change? Maybe an [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) could fit your needs.

Comment: I would like to store field values in hashmap<field, double> where double is value of field updated every time i call bind() method form Keepdata. field is name of variable, in this case myDouble

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not 100% clear but if I get you right, you want to put all annotated fields of object to the map if you invoke bind() method. It should be quite easily done with reflection.

Here you can find an example (although it is for methods not fields): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html

But you can [get annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getAnnotations()) also for [Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) objects.